# Hiding Tkinter root window while showing modal window

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have a TKinter-based application that attempts to manage settings for a game. Users may have multiple versions of this game installed, and in that case, I need to ask the user which installation they want to manage on startup. That part works well enough on its own; the selection dialog pops up after the main window is constructed, and runs modally.

However, due to differences between game versions, it would be useful if I could adapt the interface slightly for those cases. That, however, means I can't really build the main window until I know which installation I'm working on, so it's going to be blank until the user makes a choice.

I would like to hide the root window while this dialog is being shown, but calling `withdraw` on the root window simply causes the modal dialog to not be shown either - Python just ends up hanging with no CPU usage, and I can't figure out how to get around the problem without having to resort to a non-modal window (and a significantly different control flow, which I'd like to avoid).

Sample code exhibiting the problem and general code structure (Python 2.7):

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

class TkGui(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = root = Tk()
        self.root.withdraw()
        selector = FolderSelection(self.root, ('foo', 'bar'))
        self.root.deiconify()
        print(selector.result)

class ChildWindow(object): #Base class
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        top = self.top = Toplevel(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        top.title(title)
        f = Frame(top)
        self.create_controls(f)
        f.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=Y)

    def create_controls(self, container):
        pass

    def make_modal(self, on_cancel):
        self.top.transient(self.parent)
        self.top.wait_visibility() # Python will hang here...
        self.top.grab_set()
        self.top.focus_set()
        self.top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_cancel)
        self.top.wait_window(self.top) # ...or here, if wait_visibility is removed

class FolderSelection(ChildWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent, folders):
        self.parent = parent
        self.listvar = Variable(parent)
        self.folderlist = None
        super(FolderSelection, self).__init__(parent, 'Select folder')
        self.result = ''
        self.listvar.set(folders)
        self.make_modal(self.cancel)

    def create_controls(self, container):
        f = Frame(container)
        Label(
            f, text='Please select the folder '
            'you would like to use.').grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.folderlist = Listbox(
            f, listvariable=self.listvar, activestyle='dotbox')
        self.folderlist.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="nsew")
        Button(
            f, text='OK', command=self.ok
            ).grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="s")
        self.folderlist.bind("<Double-1>", lambda e: self.ok())
        f.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=Y)

    def ok(self):
        if len(self.folderlist.curselection()) != 0:
            self.result = self.folderlist.get(self.folderlist.curselection()[0])
            self.top.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', None)
            self.top.destroy()

    def cancel(self):
        self.top.destroy()

TkGui()
```

Comment: Please, explain: what is the difference - if you hide the root window - the dialog is modal or not? The results seem to be the same?

Comment: @NorthCat By making the dialog modal, the calling class will wait for the dialog to be closed before moving to the next line of code. If I use a regular window, then it will continue execution of the method, and the dialog will need to raise an event in the calling class once it's finished. That also means the dialog suddenly needs to actually *know* something about the calling class. I would very much like to avoid that, as I believe it is helpful to the overall structure and readability of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in your case there is no difference, modal window or not. In fact, you just need to use the `wait_window()` method. According the [docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm):

> In many situations, it is more practical to handle dialogs in a
>   synchronous fashion; create the dialog, display it, wait for the user
>   to close the dialog, and then resume execution of your application.
>   The wait_window method is exactly what we need; it enters a local
>   event loop, and doesn’t return until the given window is destroyed
>   (either via the destroy method, or explicitly via the window manager).

Consider follow example with nonmodal window:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def go():
   wdw = Toplevel()
   wdw.geometry('+400+400')
   e = Entry(wdw)
   e.pack()
   e.focus_set()
   #wdw.transient(root)
   #wdw.grab_set()
   root.wait_window(wdw)
   print 'done!'

Button(root, text='Go', command=go).pack()
Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.destroy).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When you click `Go` button, nonmodal dialog will appear, but code wil stop execution and the string `done!` will be displayed only after you close the dialog window.

If this is the behavior that you want, then here is your example in a modified form  (I modified `__init__` in TkGui and `make_modal` method, also added `mainloop()`):

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

class TkGui(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = root = Tk()
        self.root.withdraw()
        selector = FolderSelection(self.root, ('foo', 'bar'))
        self.root.deiconify()
        print(selector.result)

class ChildWindow(object): #Base class
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        top = self.top = Toplevel(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        top.title(title)
        f = Frame(top)
        self.create_controls(f)
        f.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=Y)

    def create_controls(self, container):
        pass

    def make_modal(self, on_cancel):
        #self.top.transient(self.parent)
        #self.top.wait_visibility() # Python will hang here...
        #self.top.grab_set()
        self.top.focus_set()
        self.top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_cancel)
        self.top.wait_window(self.top) # ...or here, if wait_visibility is removed

class FolderSelection(ChildWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent, folders):
        self.parent = parent
        self.listvar = Variable(parent)
        self.folderlist = None
        super(FolderSelection, self).__init__(parent, 'Select folder')
        self.result = ''
        self.listvar.set(folders)
        self.make_modal(self.cancel)

    def create_controls(self, container):
        f = Frame(container)
        Label(
            f, text='Please select the folder '
            'you would like to use.').grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.folderlist = Listbox(
            f, listvariable=self.listvar, activestyle='dotbox')
        self.folderlist.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="nsew")
        Button(
            f, text='OK', command=self.ok
            ).grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="s")
        self.folderlist.bind("<Double-1>", lambda e: self.ok())
        f.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=Y)

    def ok(self):
        if len(self.folderlist.curselection()) != 0:
            self.result = self.folderlist.get(self.folderlist.curselection()[0])
            self.top.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', None)
            self.top.destroy()

    def cancel(self):
        self.top.destroy()

TkGui()
mainloop()
```

The code stops on line `selector = FolderSelection(self.root, ('foo', 'bar'))` and then continue after you close the dialog.

Comment: Your answer made me realize that the problem is actually only the call to `transient`; the other two lines are fine. I never thought to remove `transient`, because that's part of what makes it a *dialog* and not a regular window, since it hides minimize and maximize - but since there won't be another window, it's okay for them to be there. Thanks!